# I am using Image picker and image cropper dependencies and trying to get image but it shows error

Tags: flutter, file-upload, imagepicker, ngx-image-cropper

I am trying to upload image into the database. I have used image picker and image cropper dependencies but it still shows error in the code within the ** that it donot recognize such commands. After the image picker it donot suggests **pickimage**. Kindly help me get through it.
class EmployeeRegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {

```
  static const id = 'employee_register';

  @override
  _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState createState() => _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState();
}

class _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState extends State<EmployeeRegistrationScreen> {

  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;
  String confirmPassword;
  bool  _passwordVisible = false;
  bool _confirmPasswordVisible = false;
  String name;

  File _imageFile;

  /// Cropper plugin
  Future<void> _cropImage() async {
    File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: _imageFile.path,
        // ratioX: 1.0,
        // ratioY: 1.0,
        // maxWidth: 512,
        // maxHeight: 512,
        **toolbarColor: Colors.purple,**
        **toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,**
        **toolbarTitle: 'Crop It'**
    );

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = cropped ?? _imageFile;
    });
  }

  /// Select an image via gallery or camera
  Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    **XFile selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);**

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selected as File;
    });
  }

  /// Remove image
  void _clear() {
    setState(() => _imageFile = null);
  }


  @override
  void initState() {

    _passwordVisible = false;
    _confirmPasswordVisible = false;

  }
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `pickImage` is not a static method, the correct way to access the `pickImage` function is to create an instance of `ImagePicker`.

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
// Pick an image
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

for Your case,

```
Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // replace ImagePicker.pickImage with ImagePicker().pickImage()
    **XFile selected = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);**

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selected as File;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It didn't worked.

Comment: as you said, it does not suggest `pickImage` after `ImagePicker`. I have seen such an issue due to conflicted imports. Make sure there is no other package that includes imagepicker. Please consider sharing all the imports and Your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: I have posted pubsec.yaml and all the imports I am using. After using your first answer it shows error on **await _picker** (The await expression can only be used in an async function.  Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*') and for _picker (The instance member '_picker' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression)

Answer (score 0):

Pubsec.yaml:

```
name: flash_chat
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.6
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - images/
```

Imports :

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/components/RoundedButton.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).